# EC2 Instance Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am able to SSH into my newly created EC2 instance (running Amazon Linux 2) with no problem. I carefully follow the [Amazon's instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html) to set up EC2 Instance Connect, yet when I try to connect using the AWS Console, I am presented with the error message below. I have tried this 4 or 5 times, each time using a fresh new EC2 instance, and I always get the same result.

Incidentally, you'll notice the [AWS instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html) indicate you must install EC2 Instance Connect using: `sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect`. When I do this I find it is already installed and all the configured files are already present. It seems as though the instance has *already* been set up for EC2 Instance Connect, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: _I am presented with the error message below_ I don't see an error message...

Comment: Even I got the same error message, for me fixing Security group inbound rule fixed the issue, also make sure you are using correct key pair

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the inbound rule only allowed SSH from my home computer's IP address. So, when I tried to connect from the AWS Console, I was denied. Obviously, I was able to SSH in from my home computer with no problem.

A newbie mistake, no doubt.